# pycparser - Getting source line number from AST

Tags: pycparser

I'm looking into parsing a C-file with pycparser and I'm trying to get the source line number from the AST generated by pycparser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the "coord" Object. Have a look at the coord class in the plyparser.py

https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pycparser/src/b169b693a194/pycparser/plyparser.py?at=default

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't exactly figure out how to use the Coord class, but having read a bit at that part of the code, it turns out, that there is a `.show()` method for AST nodes, which accepts a `showcoord` boolean argument; so you can write in your Python code:

```
ast_node.show(showcoord=True)
```

... and this will print out the structure of the node, annotated with filename and line number and column number - something like:

```
Decl: my_array, ['const'], [], ['extern'], [] (at my_header.h:41:20)
  ArrayDecl: [] (at my_header.h:41:20)
    PtrDecl: [] (at my_header.h:41:18)
      TypeDecl: my_array, ['const'], None (at my_header.h:41:20)
        IdentifierType: ['void'] (at my_header.h:41:14)
...
```